# Reference to "class" is ambigous

Tags: c++, hash, std

I would like to implement a hash table example. 
So for this aim, I have created one header, one hash.cpp and main.cpp files.
in my hash.cpp , I tried to run a dummy hash function which takes key value and turns into an index value. however, it throws an error(reference to 'hash' is ambiguous)  whenever I try to create an object according to that hash class.

this is my main.cpp:

```
#include "hash.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    hash hash_object;
    int index;
    index=hash_object.hash("patrickkluivert");

    cout<<"index="<<index<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

this is my hash.cpp:

```
#include "hash.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;

int hash(string key){
    int hash=0;
 int index;
    index=key.length();

    return index;
}
```

this is my hash.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef __hashtable__hash__
#define __hashtable__hash__
class hash
{
    public:
     int Hash(string key);

};

#endif /* defined(__hashtable__hash__) */
```

Comment: Be careful `using namespace std;`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `hash` class symbol is clashing with [std::hash](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash)

A quick fix could be using a global namespace qualifier

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  ::hash hash_object;
```

but a better **and recommended** one would be to stop polluting your global namespace with

```
using namespace std;
```

and just using `std::cout` or `std::endl` when you need them.
You could also create your own namespace in case you're writing a library.

Besides, you have some capital letter typos here:

```
index = hash_object.hash("patrickkluivert");
                    ^ I suppose you're referring to the Hash() function here
```

and here

```
int Hash(std::string key) {
    ^ this needs to be capital as well
  int hash = 0;
```

in case you want to match your declaration and avoid cast/linking errors.

Answer (score 4):

Your `hash` class is conflicting with `std::hash`. Stop using `using namespace std;` right now. If you want to make print statements shorter, try `using std::cout; using std::endl;`